# ExtJS 4 proxy Store don't consumes delivered data

Tags: rest, extjs, store, extjs4.1

I have two grids with a own proxy store each. Each store is bound to the same model with the following definition:

```
Ext.define('Issue', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [{
        name : 'updated_on',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'done_ratio',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'start_date',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'subject',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'due_date',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'created_on',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'description',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'id',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'assigned_to',
        mapping: 'assigned_to.name'
    }, {
        name: 'parked',
        mapping: 'custom_fields[9].value',
        type: 'boolean'
    }]
});
```

The stores their grids and the related container buttons etc. are created in a function. The 2 functions looks like:

```
var createMyPanel = function() {
        var store = new Ext.data.Store({
            /*sorters: ['gemeinde','assigned_to'],
            groupField: 'gemeinde',*///comment in when want enable grouping
            model : 'Issue',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoSync: true,
            proxy : {
                type : 'rest',
                url : '/issues.json',
                reader : {
                    type : 'json',
                    root : 'issues'
                },
                extraParams : runtime.CView.Model.getParams('my')
            }
        });
        var groupingFeature = new Ext.grid.feature.Grouping({
            groupHeaderTpl: 'Gemeinde: {name} ({rows.length})'
        });
        var searching = new Ext.ux.grid.feature.Searching({
            minChars: 3,
            mode: 'local',
            searchText: 'Suche einschränken',
            selectAllText: 'Alle Felder (ab)wählen',
            searchTip: '',
            minCharsTipText: 'Bitte mindestens 3 Zeichen eingeben...',
            width: 200
        });
        var commentBtn = new Ext.Button({
            text: 'Kommentar zum gewählten Ticket erfassen',
            disabled: true,
            ticket: null,
            margin: 5
        });
        var toGfBtn = new Ext.Button({
            text: 'an GIS-Fachstelle melden',
            disabled: true,
            ticket:null,
            margin: 5
        });
        var abbruchBtn = new Ext.Button({
            text: 'als abgebrochen melden',
            disabled: true,
            ticket:null,
            margin: 5
        });
        var parkBtn = new Ext.Button({
            text: 'Ticket zurücklegen',
            disabled: true,
            ticket:null,
            margin: 5
        });
        var journalPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            title: 'Kommentare',
            html:'',
            border: false,
            autoScroll: true,
            flex: 30,
            padding: '5 5 5 5'
        });
        var buttonPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            padding: '30 30 10 30',
            border: false,
            flex: 20,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items:[toGfBtn, commentBtn, abbruchBtn, parkBtn]
        });
        var contentPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            title : 'Beschreibung',
            border: false,
            html:'',
            flex: 50,
            padding: '5 5 5 5'
        });
        var southPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            padding: '0 0 5 0',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            flex: 30,
            items:[contentPanel, journalPanel, buttonPanel]
        });

        var grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
            store : store,
            autoScroll : true,
            flex: 70,
            columns : [{
                        text : 'Ticket-Nummer',
                        width : 100,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'id',
                        menuDisabled : true
                    }, {
                        text : 'Abgabe-Datum',
                        sortable : true,
                        width : 100,
                        dataIndex : 'due_date',
                        menuDisabled : true
                    }, {
                        header : 'Thema',
                        width : 200,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'subject',
                        renderer : function(val) {
                            return '<div style="white-space:normal !important;">'
                                    + val + '</div>';
                        },
                        menuDisabled : true
                    }, {
                        header : 'Gemeinde',
                        width : 200,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'gemeinde',
                        menuDisabled : true

                    }, {
                        header : 'Parzelle',
                        width : 200,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'parzelle',
                        menuDisabled : true

                    }, {
                        header : 'zurückgelegt',
                        width : 200,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'parked',
                        menuDisabled : true,
                        renderer : function(val) {
                            if(val){
                                return 'Ja';
                            }else{
                                return 'Nein';
                            }
                        },
                    },{
                        header: 'Beschreibung',
                        dataIndex: 'description',
                        hidden: true,
                        menuDisabled : true
                    }],
            bbar: ['->'],
            features: [searching/*, groupingFeature*/],//comment this in when want to group
            selModel: new Ext.selection.RowModel()
        });

        var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            title: 'Meine Fälle',
            padding: '0 5 0 5',
            bl_id:'my',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items : [grid, southPanel]
        });
        return {
            that : myPanel,
            contentPanel: contentPanel,
            grid: grid,
            store: store,
            toGfBtn:toGfBtn,
            journalPanel:journalPanel,
            commentBtn:commentBtn,
            southPanel:southPanel,
            abbruchBtn:abbruchBtn,
            parkBtn:parkBtn
        }
    };
```

and:

```
var createAllPanel = function() {
    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        /*sorters: ['gemeinde','assigned_to'],
        groupField: 'gemeinde',*///comment in when want enable grouping
        model : 'Issue',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        proxy : {
            type : 'rest',
            url : '/issues.json',
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : 'issues'
            },
            extraParams : runtime.CView.Model.getParams('all')
        }
    });
    var groupingFeature = new Ext.grid.feature.Grouping({
        groupHeaderTpl: 'Gemeinde: {name} ({rows.length})'
    });
    var searching = new Ext.ux.grid.feature.Searching({
        minChars: 3,
        mode: 'local',
        searchText: 'Suche einschränken',
        selectAllText: 'Alle Felder (ab)wählen',
        searchTip: '',
        minCharsTipText: 'Bitte mindestens 3 Zeichen eingeben...',
        width: 200
    });
    var commentBtn = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Kommentar zum gewählten Ticket erfassen',
        disabled: true,
        ticket: null,
        margin: 5
    });
    var toGfBtn = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'an GIS-Fachstelle melden',
        disabled: true,
        ticket:null,
        margin: 5
    });
    var abbruchBtn = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'als abgebrochen melden',
        disabled: true,
        ticket:null,
        margin: 5
    });
    var parkBtn = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Ticket zurücklegen',
        disabled: true,
        ticket:null,
        margin: 5
    });
    var journalPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'Kommentare',
        html:'',
        border: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        flex: 30,
        padding: '5 5 5 5'
    });
    var buttonPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        padding: '30 30 10 30',
        border: false,
        flex: 20,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items:[toGfBtn, commentBtn, abbruchBtn, parkBtn]
    });
    var contentPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title : 'Beschreibung',
        border: false,
        html:'',
        flex: 50,
        padding: '5 5 5 5'
    });
    var southPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        padding: '0 0 5 0',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        flex: 30,
        items:[contentPanel, journalPanel, buttonPanel]
    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
        store : store,
        autoScroll : true,
        flex: 70,
        columns : [{
                    text : 'Ticket-Nummer',
                    width : 100,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex : 'id',
                    menuDisabled : true
                }, {
                    text : 'Abgabe-Datum',
                    sortable : true,
                    width : 100,
                    dataIndex : 'due_date',
                    menuDisabled : true
                }, {
                    header : 'Thema',
                    width : 200,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex : 'subject',
                    renderer : function(val) {
                        return '<div style="white-space:normal !important;">'
                                + val + '</div>';
                    },
                    menuDisabled : true
                }, {
                    header : 'Gemeinde',
                    width : 200,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex : 'gemeinde',
                    menuDisabled : true

                }, {
                    header : 'Parzelle',
                    width : 200,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex : 'parzelle',
                    menuDisabled : true

                }, {
                    header : 'zugewiesen an',
                    width : 200,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex : 'assigned_to',
                    menuDisabled : true
                }, {
                    header : 'zurückgelegt',
                    width : 200,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex : 'parked',
                    menuDisabled : true,
                    renderer : function(val) {
                        if(val){
                            return 'Ja';
                        }else{
                            return 'Nein';
                        }
                    },
                },{
                    header: 'Beschreibung',
                    dataIndex: 'description',
                    hidden: true,
                    menuDisabled : true
                }],
        bbar: ['->'],
        features: [searching/*, groupingFeature*/],//comment this in when want to group
        selModel: new Ext.selection.RowModel()
    });

    var allPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'Alle Fälle',
        padding: '0 5 0 5',
        bl_id:'all',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items : [grid, southPanel]
    });
    return {
        that : allPanel,
        contentPanel: contentPanel,
        grid: grid,
        store: store,
        toGfBtn:toGfBtn,
        journalPanel:journalPanel,
        commentBtn:commentBtn,
        southPanel:southPanel,
        abbruchBtn:abbruchBtn,
        parkBtn:parkBtn
    }
};
```

As you can see the 2 panels are manly the same. When I load the page the request is started automaticly cause the stores have auto load set to true. Now the first store loads the data very well. All is fine and works like expected. What ever. The second store don't. I stalked it down to the following via firebug:

- Store is created
- store is bound correctly to proxy
- the load function is called
- data request is done
- data looks perfectly like it should
- I can inspect the answerd objects via firebug

Only the objects (which are in the browsers ) are not 'loaded' in the store. Store data items keep zero. Also after reload it again. I can't see the point here.

Something to mention: first store has around 50 items to hold the second one 220 or more. I tried to set the time out seeting for the proxy. Didn't help. I Also tried to switch the stores. Set store one to grid 2 and vice versa (it is steered by the extra params setting in the proxy). Only the store with the less amount of items loads well.

Does someone know this issue? I can't come to a conclusion for days now.

Comment: what does the returned json look like, it should be something like {"success": true, "issues": [{}, {}, ...] }

Comment: {total_count: 217

 
issues
 

[Object { updated_on=

"2013/03/12 17:17:55 +0100"

,  done_ratio=

0

,  start_date=

"2013/03/12"

,  mehr...}, Object { updated_on=

"2013/03/13 12:40:38 +0100"

,  done_ratio=

80

,  start_date=

"2013/03/12"

,  mehr...}, Object { updated_on=

"2013/03/12 14:39:24 +0100"

,  done_ratio=

0

,  start_date=

"2013/03/12"

,  mehr...}, 97 mehr...]

 
limit
 

100

 
offset
 

0

Comment: you have not configured the total and success properties, so you should use the defaults. {"success": true, "total": 217, "issues": []}

Comment: and your json data is invalid, are you generating it yourself, or using a 3rd party tool to do it?

Comment: { total_count: 217, issues:[{},{}, 97 mehr...],limit:100,offset:0} No 'success' is part of the response object. Strange is that the same response object is consumed by the first store without any problem. Sorry for the other post. problem with format :P

Comment: Well, it looks like it is something very simple, have you given both stores different store id's? You are using the same model, maybe if you are not providing store id's, ExtJS is getting confused. Another option then just trim down the code to generate and load the stores remove everything else, like search tools, grids, etc.

Comment: good hint with the store id's I tried that. But nothing changes. I try now to change the version of ext. Maybe?! Who knows. After that I must go down the hard road of code triming and try and error. Thanks again for spending time on that. I let you know if I can find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out Proxy Configuration from Sencha's docs.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-totalProperty

and your json is not in valid json format, verify it in json viewers for errors.

EDIT: You can listen to exceptions thrown by the data reader:  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-event-exception

Comment: I checked the delivered json in JSONLint. It says it is valid!? And all shuold be ok. It loads the data well in the first store. The only difference to the second store is that in the request parameters (same request url by the way) a filter is set to get specific objects. I can't agree with your answer. sorry.

Comment: set the total property does not help. My understanding of that is, that this property is needed if server delivers paged data. My server !can! do that but isn't at the moment. I delivers up to 2000 objects unpaged.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because of some missconfig on server side the bigger bunch of the objects which are delivered contains 1 object which doesn't fit to the model (had to check 217 objects -.-). This seem to broke the store at all. Now when I fixed that problem all works as expected. Anyway: It is strange, that no error was thrown by store that data could not read. Could that a request to sencha maybe?

Comment: Were you listening to the Readers exception events, maybe it was throwing an exception. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-event-exception

Comment: No. But this is what I do as standard in future! :) I don't want do a search like that again... Thanks!